# Dynamic XML based chart for showing database information

Tags: php, xml, charts

Can any one, please tell me is there any open source available for showing database order information into graphical chart using PHP-XML?

Comment: Can you further develop the concept "order information"?

Comment: This is a very ambiguous question.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search i had find the best way to integrate the fusioncharts which is exactly match my requirement.

```
www.fusioncharts.com
```